# Всплывающее окно ошибки от input

Tags: javascript, php

Как можно сделать всплывающее окно ошибки, от `input`, если обязательный `input` не заполнен, при нажатии кнопки отправки формы на сайт?

Comment: Проверка на стороне клиента или сервера?

Comment: @Вася не вандалируйте вопрос, Спасибо.

Comment: простите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax.

```
// функция валидации с определенными правилами, ее можно будет использовать и для валидации на сервере после отправки
    function Validate ($fname ,$fvalue, $fclass)
    {
        $classes = explode(' ', $fclass);
        $error = array('trigger' => FALSE, 'msg' => array());

        foreach ($classes as $class)
        {
            // проверяем в соответствии с правилами
            switch ($class)
            {
                case 'noempty':
                    if (trim($fvalue) == '')
                    {
                        $error['trigger']   = TRUE;
                        $error['msg'][]     = '<div class="error msg" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">поле ' . $fname . ' не может быть пустым</div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'email':
                    if (!filter_var($fvalue, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                    {
                        $error['trigger']   = TRUE;
                        $error['msg'][]     = '<div class="error msg" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">поле ' . $fname . ' не является почтой</div>';
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        // если ошибок не возникло, то значение поля считаеться допустимым
        if (!$error['trigger'])
        {
            $error['msg'][]    = '<div class="ok msg" style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">ок</div>';
        }

        return $error;
    }

    // непосредственно валидация
    if (isset($_POST['validation']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['validation'] as $field_name => $field)
        {
            $validate = Validate($field_name, $field['value'], $field['class']);
            foreach ($validate['msg'] as $msg)
            {
                // выводим ответ
                echo $msg;
            }
        }
        // прекращаем выполнение
        exit();
    }
```

[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/35782/)

Comment: Зачем с бэкенда такое отправлять: `'<div class="error msg" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">поле ' . $fname . ' не может быть пустым</div>';`?

Comment: Зачем вообще всё это? Проверяем на стороне клиента, а после отправки уже на стороне сервера, если у клиента JS там отключен например. И если ошибка - возвращаем на страницу с формой.

Comment: Да я вас спрашиваю про то, зачем вы через `echo` кусок разметки со стилями "выплевываете"?

Comment: Это код с источника. Болтался у меня в закладках - вот и вспомнил. Просто дал ссылку, но здесь заругались. Скопипастил кусок кода. Я ответил про суть вопроса - предложил Ajax.